# Animated Punching Sounds

Tags: animation, sound-design, sound-effects, sound-effects-recording

Hey guys, I'm working on a 3D animated film that contains a fight scene between two people. I've always been a huge fan of Robert Hargreaves and his work (he does the sound design for all of the DC comic animated films/shows).

However, I'm having trouble replicating his punching sounds. They don't sound like your typical "punch some meat / crunch some celery" combo that most realistic punches are. Anyone have some insight on what they think I can record to replicate this sound?

Here is a sample of his work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmTg7ROPssc

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It almost sounds like some gunshots or thunder, with short decays, layered in with the punch sounds.

Comment: Yea I had thought the same thing. I also thought I might try slapping a piece of wood in a garage. Thanks for the help!